# Use same key k in deterministic counter mode to encrypt two different plaintext

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, xor, ctr

What goes wrong if we use the **same key k** in deterministic **counter mode** to encrypt two different plaintext messages m0 /= m1.

It is not true that c0 = c1, because we XOR output of m0 with input of m1 in counter mode. As a result, c0 cannot equal c1, and c1 cannot be said to be the same as c0.

**Could this be true?**

> Attacker find two c0 and c1, then find m0 and m1.
>
> Currently, attackers can check all new messages they send or receive. He found the key using ciphertext and plaintext.

Comment: Is this homework?  If you're asking because you're thinking of doing this in practice, well, **don't do that**

Comment: Yes, but I'l final exam start about 9hours ago. I need last true answer.

Comment: Are you using a different nonce?

Comment: @forest yes, using diffrent nonce.

Comment: @forest yes, using diffrent nonce.

Answer (score 3):

This is a homework question; by policy, we don't give the final answer to homework questions - you learn better if you figure the answer out yourself.

That said, we will give hints - here are a couple:

- If we have $C_0 = P_0 \oplus AESCTR_{key}$ and $C_1 = P_1 \oplus AESCRT_{key}$, how are $C_0$ and $C_1$ related?
- If we can deduce $P_0 \oplus P_1$, can we use that to recover $P_0, P_1$?  Actually, that depends on the distribution that $P_0, P_1$ are drawn from - for some common distributions (e.g. ASCII English) we can.